# How to get the instance variable of the current controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to use the following partial in various views across different controllers. Is there a way to replace `@person` with a more general variable that simply calls the instance variable of the current controller, not matter if it's `@person` or `@user` or `@company` or whatever?

```
<% content_for(:timestamps) do %>
    <p>Created: <%= l @person.created_at, :format => :long %>, Last updated: <%= l @person.updated_at, :format => :long %></p>
<% end %>
```

Thanks for any help.

This is my helper function based on Xavier's code:

```
def timestamps
  content_for(:timestamps) do
    current_string = controller.controller_name.singularize
    current_object = instance_variable_get("@#{current_string}")
    created_at_time = l(current_object.created_at, :format => :long)
    updated_at_time = l(current_object.updated_at, :format => :long)
    text = "Created: #{created_at_time}, Last updated: #{updated_at_time}"
    content_tag(:p, text)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is doable.  Try this:

```
<% content_for(:timestamps) do %>
<% current_string = controller.controller_name.singularize %>
<% current_object = instance_variable_get("@#{current_string}") %>
    <p>Created: <%= l current_object.created_at, :format => :long %>, Last updated: <%= l current_object.updated_at, :format => :long %></p>
<% end %>
```

Of course, you'll want to do error/nil checking.  And if you're an MVC purist (or just like clean code), you'll probably want to move it to a helper.  But it's a functional starting point.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That works great, thanks a lot! I moved the code into a helper function inside `application_helper.rb` and posted it above. How would I check for errors or nils here? Not sure if my syntax is that good either.

Comment: @Tintin81 - Just make sure `current_object` isn't nil before using it.  This is in case this helper gets called from `user_index`, say, and there is no specific `user` to work with.  That's all I can imagine going wrong...  Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Define in each controller a method that gives the element you're looking for. For exemple, in `PersonController`

```
 def current_element 
   @person
 end
```

And define this method as a helper in the `ApplicationController`, so the method is usable from the views

```
 helper_method :current_element
```

Use this method result as a parameter of you partial :

_the_partial.html.erb

```
<% content_for(:timestamps) do %>
    <p>Created: <%= l element.created_at, :format => :long %>, Last updated: <%= l @person.updated_at, :format => :long %></p>
<% end %>
```

and in your views:

```
render :partial => 'the_partial', :locals => { :element => current_element }
```

Comment: Thanks! I am sure this will work also but I have a whole bunch of controllers and not sure if I want to add that line to all of those. Cheers!